# Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, database

I have this MySQL query which was selecting data correctly until i joined another table (afk_measures_childs) and gives me this error :
" #1054 - Unknown column 'md.org_date' in 'on clause' "

```
select md.id,md.value,md.text_ar,md.photo,md.created_date org_date,mc.ar_title from afk_map_data md,afk_measures_childs mc
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id,max(created_date) max_date from afk_map_data) t 
on 
t.max_date = md.org_date
WHERE
md.measures_child_id = mc.id
AND
md.map_id = 1
AND
md.state_id = 1
AND
md.measures_id= 1 
order by md.id
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix the old implicit and the new explicit join syntax.

```
select md.id,md.value,md.text_ar,md.photo,md.created_date org_date,mc.ar_title 
from afk_map_data md
JOIN afk_measures_childs mc on md.measures_child_id = mc.id
JOIN 
(
   SELECT id, max(created_date) max_date 
   from afk_map_data
) t on t.max_date = md.org_date
WHERE md.map_id = 1
AND md.state_id = 1
AND md.measures_id= 1 
order by md.id
```

Comment: Its working perfect , thanks a lot ,sorry its was my fault i just removed the alias org_date and worked as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You have not properly set an inner join with alias

```
select md.id,md.value,md.text_ar,md.photo,md.created_date org_date, mc.ar_title 
from afk_map_data md
INNER JOIN afk_measures_childs mc on md.measures_child_id = mc.id 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id,max(created_date) max_date from afk_map_data) t 
    on t.max_date = md.org_date
where
md.map_id = 1
AND
md.state_id = 1
AND
md.measures_id= 1 
order by md.id
```